# SQLite : Wrong ID when i create a new item after an elimination

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-delete

I made the field `id autoincrement` and when I create an item there are no problems. The problem starts when i delete an item: the item is correctly deleted only if there are in the database all the items with a lower id compared to the one I want to delete.

Here is an example:

```
id       item
-----------------
1        swim
2        tennis
3        football
4        baseball
```

When I delete baseball is all ok, but if I create a new item after the elimination of baseball it has the id = 5

For example:

```
id       item
------------------
1        swim
2        tennis
3        football
5        rugby
```

So, now the elimination of rugby needs **2 clicks** (instead of one) on the image I made clickable into a clickable recyclerview in order to delete the item. This happens because the first element under rugby has id = 3 and not 4.

Another example: in the database I have only a item with id = 18 , for delete it I have to click 18 times because the id is decremented while it become 1 and then it is deleted.

I don't know how to make the autoincrement column id restart its autoincrementation from the highest id into the database, or if there are no items make it restart from 1.

This is the `delete` (I use the variable j because position starts from 0):

```
public void deleteEntry(int position) {
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = getWritableDatabase();
        int j = position + 1;
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + SportEntry.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " +
                SportEntry._ID + " = " + j + ";");
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("UPDATE " + SportEntry.TABLE_NAME + " SET " + SportEntry._ID + " = " +
                SportEntry._ID + " -1 " + " WHERE " + SportEntry._ID + " > " + j + ";");
    }
```

This is the onCreate in the dbHelper class:

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String SQL_CREATE_SPORT_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "("
            + SportEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + SportEntry.COLUMN_ATTIVITA + " TEXT NOT NULL);"; 
        db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_SPORT_TABLE);
    }
```

This is the contract class:

```
public final class SportContract {

    private SportContract(){}

    public static final class SportEntry implements BaseColumns {
        public static final String TABLE_NAME = "sport";
        public static final String _ID = BaseColumns._ID;
        public static final String COLUMN_ATTIVITA = "Attivita";
    }
}
```

Comment: Why should other row ids change when you delete one row in the middle?

Comment: Is there any reason why your list doesn't hold ID and pass it back to `deleteEntry` instead of position?

Comment: This is the problem, they should not but they do @laalto

Comment: I thought that if I pass the position it delete the element in that position. If I pass the ID is it updated if I delete an element ?@Pawel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code allow me to take the corrrect ID of the selected item:
Into the DbHelper, this is the funcition `delete`:

```
public void deleteEntry(int position) {
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = getWritableDatabase();
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + SportEntry.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " +
                SportEntry._ID + " = " + position + ";");
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("UPDATE " + SportEntry.TABLE_NAME + " SET " + SportEntry._ID + " = " +
                SportEntry._ID + " -1 " + " WHERE " + SportEntry._ID + " > " + position + ";");
}
```

`OnDeleteClick` function into the main activity ( when i click the image corresponding to the item into the recyclerview allow me to delete the item):

```
@Override
public void onDeleteClick (int position) {
       int x = ReadID(position);
       removeItem(x);
}
```

`removeItem` function into the main activity:

```
public void removeItem(int position) {
       mDbHelper.deleteEntry(position);
       mAdapter.swapCursor(mDbHelper.getAllItems());
}
```

This is function into the main class that allow me to take the correct ID:

```
    public int ReadID(int position){
         mDbHelper = new SportDbHelper(this);
         SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
         String[] projection = {BaseColumns._ID,
            };

         String sortOrder = SportEntry._ID + " ASC";

         Cursor cursor = db.query(
                 SportEntry.TABLE_NAME,   // The table to query
                 projection,             // The array of columns to return (null to get all)
                 null,              // The columns for the WHERE clause
                 null,              // The values for the WHERE clause
                 null,              // null if you don't want to group the rows
                 null,              // null if you don't want filter by row groups
                 sortOrder          // the order
         );
         try {
         int idColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(SportEntry._ID);
             int currentID  = 0;
             int cg=0;
         while ((cursor.moveToNext() == true) && (cg != (position + 1))) {
             currentID = cursor.getInt(idColumnIndex);
             cg ++;

            }
         return currentID;
         } finally {
        cursor.close();
    }

}
```

For completeness, this is the `getAllItems()` function into the `DbHelper` class:

```
public Cursor getAllItems() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();

        return db.query(
                SportEntry.TABLE_NAME,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null
        );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> When I delete baseball is all ok, but if I create a new item after the
> elimination of baseball it has the id = 5

This is the right flow as per database because the id is set to autoincrement as well it is a primary key.

> So, now the elimination of rugby needs 2 clicks (instead of one) on
> the image I made clickable into a clickable recyclerview in order to
> delete the item.

This is not the correct to handle click events to access that particular item on recyclerview. If you keep doing this way then when the records reaches 200 item you cant keep clicking 200 times.

To do this in a better way use the id of each record as the where clause to fetch all of its corresponsing records and show in the new activity.