# Android, delete item in list and in sqllite java

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview

> ATTENTION AT THE END OF THE QUESTION IS THE UPDATE BUT STILL NOT
> WORKING

Hey everyone I'm having a list and a popup where I can click on **delete**.

How can I delete the item which I long click in my list
***This list is stored in the local sqllite db.***

***I wanna click delete to delete the Edinbourgh item***

[image]

My Code for the list:

```
public class ViewListContents extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseHelper myDB;

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.popup_layout, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.viewcontents_layout);

        ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);
        myDB = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        final MenuItem deleteItem, editItem;

        final ArrayList<String> theList = new ArrayList<>();
        final Cursor data = myDB.getListContents();

        final ListAdapter listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, theList);
        listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        deleteItem = findViewById(R.id.delete_item);
        editItem = findViewById(R.id.edit_item);

        final ListView finalListView = listView;
        listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, final int position, final long id) {
                PopupMenu p = new PopupMenu(ViewListContents.this, v);
                MenuInflater inflater = p.getMenuInflater();
                inflater.inflate(R.menu.popup_layout, p.getMenu());
                p.show();

                //Listener wait for the click on the popup menu item
                p.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                item.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        switch (item.getItemId()) {
                            case R.id.delete_item:

                                finalListView.getItemAtPosition(position);
                                myDB.deleteEntry(finalListView.getSelectedItemPosition());
                                ((ArrayAdapter) listAdapter).remove(listAdapter.getItem(position));
                                ((ArrayAdapter) listAdapter).notifyDataSetChanged();
                                int x = ReadID(position);
                                myDB.deleteEntry(x);
                                myDB.getAllItems(Contract.YourEntry.COL2);
                                return true;

                            case R.id.edit_item:
                                getTheme();
                                return true;

                            default:
                                return true; //return ViewListContents.super.onOptionsItemSelected(deleteItem);
                        }
                    }
                });

/*                @Override
                public boolean onOptionsItemSelected() {
                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.delete_item:
                            theList.remove(position);
                            return true;
                        case R.id.edit_item:
                            getTheme();
                            return true;
                        default:
                            return ViewListContents.super.onOptionsItemSelected(deleteItem);
                    }
                }*/

/*                deleteItem.setOnActionExpandListener("Ok", new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                       theList.remove(position);
                        finalListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
                    }
                });*/
                return true;
            }
        });

        if (data.getCount() == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(ViewListContents.this, "Your list is empty :(", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            while (data.moveToNext()) {
                theList.add(data.getString(1));
                listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
            }
        }
    }

    public int ReadID(int position){
        DatabaseHelper mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        String[] projection = {Contract.YourEntry.COL2};

        String sortOrder = Contract.YourEntry.COL2 + " ASC";

        Cursor cursor = db.query(
                Contract.YourEntry.TABLE_NAME,   // The table to query
                null,             // The array of columns to return (null to get all)
                null,              // The columns for the WHERE clause
                null,              // The values for the WHERE clause
                null,              // null if you don't want to group the rows
                null,              // null if you don't want filter by row groups
                sortOrder          // the order
        );
        try {
            int idColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(Contract.YourEntry.intWhereToGoListOID);
            int currentID  = 0;
            int count = 0;
            while ((cursor.moveToNext() == true) && (count != (position + 1))) {
                currentID = cursor.getInt(idColumnIndex + 1);
                count ++;

            }
            return currentID;
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }

    }

}
```

And here's my DB code:

```
    public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // DATABASE
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mylist.db";

    // TABLES
    public static final String TABLE_TWHERETOGOLIST = "TWhereToGoList";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME_2 = "TCategories";
    public static final String TABLE_TListDefiniton = "TListDefinition";

    // COLUMNS FOR TABLE: TWhereToGoList
    public static final String intWhereToGoListOID = "WhereToGoListOID";
    public static final String COL2 = "COL2";
    public static final String intCategoriesOID = "CategoriesOID ";
    public static final DateFormat dtDateLastModified = DateFormat.getDateInstance();

    Date c = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
    public String formattedDate = df.format(c);

    public static final String strDescription = "Description";
    public static final String strGoogleLink = "GoogleLink";
    public static final Integer bVisited = 0;
    public static final Integer bRecommend = 0;
    public static final Integer intListDefinitionOID = 0;

    // COLUMNS FOR TABLE: TCategories
    public static final Integer getIntListDefinitionOID = 0;
    //public static final String strTitle = "strTitle";                 // Both can get called from the top
    //public static final String strDescription = "strDescription";     // Both can get called from the top


    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.deleteDatabase(new File(DATABASE_NAME));
        String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_TWHERETOGOLIST + " (intWhereToGoListOID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                + " COL2 TEXT, " + " intCategoriesOID TEXT, " + " strDescription TEXT, "
                + " strGoogleLink TEXT, " + " bVisited INTEGER)";
        db.execSQL(createTable);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL(String.format("DROP IF TABLE EXISTS ", TABLE_TWHERETOGOLIST));
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public boolean addData(String string) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL2, string);

        long result = db.insert(TABLE_TWHERETOGOLIST, null, contentValues);

        //if date as inserted incorrectly it will return -1
        if (result == -1) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public Cursor getListContents() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor data = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_TWHERETOGOLIST, null);
        return data;
    }

    /*public int delete(int position) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        if (db == null) {
            Logger.getLogger("The DB is empty");
        }

        db.delete(TABLE_TWHERETOGOLIST, COL2 + " = ?", new String[]{ (intWhereToGoListOID) }); //new String[]{Long.toString(positionOfId)} );
```

***ANOTHER UPDATE:***
Probably the problem is the -1 which you see at the last line in this quote here.
If I write there something else after the click on the delete button and looking from the main activity again back to the list the text gets replaced by the number and some elements get deleted and other gets a number or some text which i can write to the -1.
In another situation if i go some more times through this cyclus the numbers get summarize and just creepy.

> ```
> public void deleteEntry(int position) {
>         SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = getWritableDatabase();
>
>         sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + Contract.YourEntry.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " +
>                 Contract.YourEntry.COL2 + " = " + position + ";");
>         sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("UPDATE " + Contract.YourEntry.TABLE_NAME + " SET " + Contract.YourEntry.COL2 +
>                 " = " + Contract.YourEntry.COL2 + " -1 " + " WHERE " + Contract.YourEntry.COL2 + " > " + position + ";");
>     }
> ```

```
        Logger.getLogger("Successfully deleted the item!!!");
        //Logger.getLogger(String.valueOf(getListContents()));
        db.close();
        return 1;
    }

    public Cursor getAllItems() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();

        return db.query(
                TABLE_TWHERETOGOLIST,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null
        );
    }


}
```

***If you're having any questions ask me in the comments below.
Thanks for your reply :)***

> UPDATE 1.0:

I've now the problem that I don't know how I could take the ID of the ListView Item I longclicked and pressed delete on the popup which occurs.

I've to get the (ID whatever) of this ListView Item to my DB code to delete this item.

Please ask if you have questions.

Please describe in DETAIL :)
I don't know how I can do this

Comment: I'm afraid I don't follow?

Comment: @EyosiyasBerketab I wanna delete a ListView item in my application while pressing on the popup section delete. But I can't delete the item.

Comment: Does myDB.delete(theList.get(position)); delete the record?

Comment: @EyosiyasBerketab it should but I am not really sure.

Comment: Test that first and after that, you have to notify the Adapter the data has been changed.

Comment: @EyosiyasBerketab okay give me a minute, I think there is a problem in my WHERE clausel

Can you give my question an upvote = more people will see it and it probably helps for them

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222772/discussion-between-eyosiyas-berketab-and-noah).

Comment: okay sounds nice

Comment: Create a demo application, I will check

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya so you will create one or do you mean that I have to create one?

Comment: @Noah Issue solved?

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya no sorry i was away for a day :)

Comment: @Noah Kindly create a short demo and share code in git. I will check

Comment: Now it is solved by 1/2 because I have now the problem that my entire list gets deleted.

        `db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_TWHERETOGOLIST + " WHERE " +              
                COL2 + " = " + position + ";");                                     
        db.execSQL("UPDATE " + TABLE_TWHERETOGOLIST + " SET " + COL2 +              
                " = " + COL2 + " -1 " + " WHERE " + COL2 + " > " + position + ";"); 

`

@IntelliJAmiya

Answer (score 1):

When you click delete you have to call the `delete` function and pass the `ID` of the element you want to delete to this function.
In order to do this you have to read the elements into the `database` and pick the one you selected.  
I think that one problem should be that `position` starts from zero and the elements into the database from position 1, so you have to consider that.
This should be the function for read elements:
(Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64242895/sqlite-wrong-id-when-i-create-a-new-item-after-an-elimination) for more, it may be useful for you)
UPDATE: adapted as your are using a contract class

```
    public int ReadID(int position){
         mDbHelper = new YourDbHelper(this);
         SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
         String[] projection = {BaseColumns.intWhereToGoListOID,
            };

         String sortOrder = YourEntry.intWhereToGoListOID+ " ASC";

         Cursor cursor = db.query(
                 YourEntry.TABLE_NAME,   // The table to query
                 projection,             // The array of columns to return (null to get all)
                 null,              // The columns for the WHERE clause
                 null,              // The values for the WHERE clause
                 null,              // null if you don't want to group the rows
                 null,              // null if you don't want filter by row groups
                 sortOrder          // the order
         );
         try {
         int idColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(YourEntry.intWhereToGoListOID);
             int currentID  = 0;
             int count=0;
         while ((cursor.moveToNext() == true) && (count != (position + 1))) {
             currentID = cursor.getInt(idColumnIndex);
             count ++;

            }
         return currentID;
         } finally {
        cursor.close();
    }

}
```

UPDATE:
To be clearer use a contract class where you define your table of the database. If you use it you can refere to elements like YourEntry.name_of_the_column (you have to import the class before ex: import .com.example. ... .YourContract.YourEntry ).
This is a `contract class` example:

```
import android.provider.BaseColumns;

public class YourContract {

    private YourContract(){}

    public static final class YourEntry implements BaseColumns {
        public static final String TABLE_NAME = "TABLE_TWHERETOGOLIST";
        public static final String intWhereToGoListOID = BaseColumns.intWhereToGoListOID;
        public static final String COL2 = "COL2";
        public static final String intCategoriesOID = "CategoriesOID ";
        /*Other columns*/
    }
}
```

(so you have to change your onCreate adapting it with YourEntry.collum or YourEntry.TABLE_NAME, example in the link above)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223195/discussion-on-answer-by-riccardo-storchi-android-delete-item-in-list-and-in-sql).